SwiftUI unable to pass EnvironmentValues through child view
I have a SwiftUI view(lets call it X) which consists of different components. One of the component(lets call it Y) is setting a EnvironmentValues(backgroundType) for its downward hierarchy which is different than set by parent view X.
struct ParentViewX: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .visible(let data):
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(data.header) { component in
                            component.buildWith(action: viewModel.handleAction)
                        }
                    }
                    .environment(\.backgroundType, data.header.background)
                }
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}

While building different components, there's a component called Badge which passes a different value for backgroundType.
struct Badge: SwiftUI.View {
    struct Model: ComponentModelType {
        let id: String = "\(UUID())"
        let label: MyText.Model
        let background: Background
    }

    let model: Model

    var body: some SwiftUI.View {
        MyText(model: model.label)
            .environment(\.backgroundType, model.background)
    }
}

struct MyText: View {
    struct Model: ComponentModelType {
        let id: String = "\(UUID())"
        let content: String
        let color: MyTextColor?
    }

    let model: Model
    @Environment(\.backgroundType) var backgroundType

    var body: some View {
        Label(model.content)
            .textColor(model.color ?? textColor())
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }

    private func textColor() -> MyTextColor {
        switch backgroundType {
        case .one:
            return .primary
        case .two:
            return .secondary
        default:
            return .primaryInverse
        }
    }
}

So MyText should receive the value of backgroundType to be .two because its passed by Badge. However, it receives the value of .one.
I cant seem to figure out what could be the issue!
What am I doing wrong?

pls update question showing minimum reproducible code. I can't find where is Badge being used as a view.

Below code builds all the components. "component" is of a custom component type which is an enum and when buildWith function is called it initialises relevant component.
ForEach(data.header) { component in
component.buildWith(action: viewModel.handleAction)
}

In SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already. Try using @State.

@malhal Do you mean defining model inside Badge and MyText as @State?

Using @State doesnt work either.

@ParasGorasiya I mean remove ViewModel

@malhal I am not sure I understand your suggestion. What does ViewModel has to do with EnvironmentValues? Its completely unrelated and used for handling actions from different components.

If it has actions it should be a Controller. In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model, i.e. holds the view data, so you shouldn't have an environment object called a view model because you shouldn't have shared mutable view data in an object because that is a source of bugs and is the problem the View struct hierarchy is designed to solve.

Perhaps there's some misunderstanding, ViewModel is not environment object. BackgroundType is environment object which is an enum type.
